# Is it possible to use different checkers with different flycheck-check-syntax-automatically?

Tags: flycheck

I have two checkers `fast-checker` and `slow-checker`. So I want to use `fast-checker` with `flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(idle-change)` and `slow-checker` with `flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(save)`.

Is it possible?

Or at least can I use `flycheck-buffer` with specific checker?
So I could do something like this

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () (flycheck-buffer `slow-checker)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither of these are possible, but you can add a `:predicate` to the slow checker that checks for `flycheck-buffer-saved-p` to achieve the same effect.